# What is your favorite HexEditor?

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, default-programs

What are the most available open source GUI hex-editor for the Ubuntu LTS 14.04 Desktop? I have HexEdit running on OS X, and am looking for something similar. A bit more modern perhaps, with good functionality, stability, easily installed and integrated. This is a system for a novice programming student learning Linux and examining code. how would you compare: Ghex, Bless, and wxHex? Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[**Bless**](http://home.gna.org/bless/) is a high quality full featured hex editor.

Bless currently provides the following features:

- Efficient editing of large data files and block devices.
- Multilevel undo - redo operations.
- Customizable data views.
- Fast data rendering on screen.
- Multiple tabs.
- Fast find and replace operations.
- Advanced copy/paste capabilities.
- Highlighting of selection pattern matches in the file.
- Export to text and html (others with plugins).
- Extensibility with Plugins.

You can compare hex editors [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors).

Installation:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and run:

`sudo apt-get install bless`

**Alternatively**
click this [link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/bless/).

Comment: fyi: this is a ***mono app*** and will pull all the mono runtime dependencies.

Comment: @ccpizza what is the implication of this?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty it means you'll have to download the full Mono framework and all its dependencies (probably a few hundred MB) just to run that software. Hidden message is "probably not worth it" ;)

Comment: Bless constantly crashed on me. Was not impressed at all, and felt limited.

Comment: It kept on crashing till i removed it.

Comment: Bless does not work with device blocks.

Comment: omg... I ran this app twice and it crashed... twice... uninstalled it asap :(

Answer (score 25):

I have been using wxHexEditor - full featured / stable + source !

Handles HUGE files with ease (only limited by your RAM)

```
sudo apt-get install wxhexeditor  #  then launch using  wxHexEditor
```

___ OR ___

```
git clone https://github.com/EUA/wxHexEditor.git 
cd wxHexEditor
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
wxHexEditor
```

Before compiling wxHexeditor you need wxWidgets and autoreconf on your system ... just install those libraries :

```
sudo apt-get build-dep  wxhexeditor
```

if `make` gives you this error

```
make: *** No rule to make target '-lgomp', needed by 'src/HexEditorGui.o'.  Stop.
```

then edit file `Makefile` and remove this line

```
LIBS += -lgomp
```

for details see https://github.com/EUA/wxHexEditor/issues/150

I then do

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wxHexEditor /usr/local/bin/wxhexeditor
```

so I can launch it using lowercase  `wxhexeditor`

Comment: It looks like Ghex, and Bless are more available through the package add system, but I definitely want to give wxHex a try, it seems to get some pretty positive reviews. My next step should be to learn how to compile wxHex, and get it installed. Thanks for the tip!